# MongoDB and GridFS

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, gridfs, nosql

We've a big existing project with thousands of users each day. We use MySQL but now we are planning to use MongoDB (and GridFS) now.

Can MongoDB and GridFS be used for larger projects ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB and GridFS can most definitely be used for large projects. There are several examples of that working successfully, such as with foursquare (see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments#ProductionDeployments-SocialNetworks).

Moving from a relational database to MongoDB is however not really straight forward. MongoDB comes with a new mind set on modeling data, and how you insert, update, and query data is hugely important for its performance characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

I've used GridFS to store around million JPEG files. Worked fine for me. MongoDB is OK for key/value storage.

I would be more cautious moving whole database from SQL to MongoDb, since complex queries optimization is not that transparent compared to tools available in SQL databases.

(Moved my project from MongoDB to PostgreSQL because of that)